# Mono/ MVC3 Only home page displays, everything else is 404

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, ubuntu, mono

Scratching my head here.  I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS with the latest mono that it comes with.  My windows dev box works fine, but on the linux box the only page that comes up is the default home page... less the CSS and scripts.  Looking at the debug tools, it looks like everything else gets a 404.

There's a similar scenario on SO for IIS6, suggesting that this may be an issue of mono trying to use the wrong framework version, but I can't figure out where to tell it differently, and I'm not convinced that is the problem.

Does anyone have insight into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the issue: my apache configuration was not set up correctly.  I had a conflicting hostname in one of my enabled site files, and it seems apache got confused.  clearing out the rubbish and restarting apache2 fixed the problem.